# Jmeter - HTTP Headers

Tags: jmeter

I recorded a web page using JMeter which has produced several samplers. Each of those samplers (http request) has a config HTTP Header Manager. Is it really necessary to have that for each sampler or can I just maintain one at the thread group level.  Of course some of those Headers have referer header element and some don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need one header per request, unless each request need a unique header.

You may not even need ONE at the threadgroup / test plan level, unless you are wanting to specify header information.

When you record, there is a checkbox in the HTTP Proxy to toggle capturing these.

Comment: Well in some cases you will actually need these headers: it's when the application checks for the referer field in some steps.

Most of .NET applications do that, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough one Header Manager per Thread. See documantation http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager